# Android - If then doesn't work..?

Tags: java, android

I am hitting a huge wall here. I got this code which checks on database result :

```
chosenSlotDAO.open();
        Log.d("id", chosenSlotDAO.getId());
        Log.d("isParked", chosenSlotDAO.getIsParked());
        Log.d("parkedRow", chosenSlotDAO.getParkedRow());
        Log.d("selectedSlot", chosenSlotDAO.getSelectedSlot());
        String idStatus = chosenSlotDAO.getId();
        String isParkedStatus = chosenSlotDAO.getIsParked();
        String parkedRowStatus = chosenSlotDAO.getParkedRow();
        String selectedSlotStatus = chosenSlotDAO.getSelectedSlot();
        final String outputA = this.getOutput(this, slotA);

        if(idStatus == id && isParkedStatus == isParked && parkedRowStatus != parkedA && selectedSlotStatus != slotA)
        {
            arriveTView.setText(alreadyParked + chosenSlotDAO.getParkedRow());
        }
        else if(idStatus == id && isParkedStatus == isNotParked && parkedRowStatus != parkedA && selectedSlotStatus != slotA)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                wrongParkingRow, 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            chosenSlotDAO.updateSlot(id, slotA, parkedA, isParked);
        }
        else if(idStatus == id && isParkedStatus == isParked && parkedRowStatus == parkedA && selectedSlotStatus == slotA)
        {
            chosenSlotDAO.updateSlot(id, slotA, setEmpty, isNotParked);

            dbUpdateAdd.execute(slotA);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(ParkAArrive.this, ParkLeaving.class);
            ParkAArrive.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
        else if(outputA.isEmpty())
        {
            arriveTView.setText(isFull);
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    nowParked, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            chosenSlotDAO.updateSlot(id, slotA, parkedA, isParked);
            arriveTView.setText(chosenSlotDAO.getSelectedSlot());
            dbUpdate.execute(slotA);
        }
```

The class is started by tapping an NFC tag.

LogCat returns :

```
06-15 04:35:10.818: D/id(12294): 1
06-15 04:35:10.818: D/isParked(12294): 1
06-15 04:35:10.819: D/parkedRow(12294): ParkedA
06-15 04:35:10.819: D/selectedSlot(12294): SlotA
06-15 04:35:10.829: D/link(12294): http://parkit.byethost9.com/db_show_slot.php?slot_name=SlotA
06-15 04:35:11.681: D/line(12294): 14
```

It clearly shows that user is parked, parkedRow is ParkedA, and SlotA is SlotA. But the `if` does not work.

But when I start the activity again, nothing except

```
else if(outputA.isEmpty())
        {
            arriveTView.setText(isFull);
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    nowParked, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            chosenSlotDAO.updateSlot(id, slotA, parkedA, isParked);
            arriveTView.setText(chosenSlotDAO.getSelectedSlot());
            dbUpdate.execute(slotA);
        }
```

works.

Where in the code am I doing wronggg?? Tell me if I left any required info untold..

UPDATE :
It seems that I need to change my code so that it can compare `String`, and yes it's the problem I'm facing.

Comment: You should reformulate you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `equals` method to compare `String` objects instead of `the == operator`.

See the following question for a full explanation: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)